# Dam break problem for shallow water equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

This problem concerns the shallow water equations

$\partial_tu+u\partial_xu+g\partial_xh=0$

$\partial_th+u\partial_xh+h\partial_xu=0$.

where $g$ is a constant. Water of depth $h_0$ is at rest for $x > 0$, held back by a vertical dam at
$x = 0$. At $t = 0$, the dam breaks, and water pours into the region $x<0$

I have shown that the Riemann invariants $F_{\pm}=u\pm2c$, where $c=\sqrt{gh}$, are constant along characteristics with $\frac{dx_{\pm}}{dt}=u\pm c$. I have also shown that both the $+$ and $-$ characteristics are straight lines for $x>\sqrt{gh_0}t$.

**I am struggling with this part**

Consider a point $(x_p,t_p)$ immediately to the left of the line $x=\sqrt{gh_0}t$, so that the $x_-$ characteristic began in the region $x>\sqrt{gh_0}t$.

I need to show that the $x_+$ characteristic passing through this point is a straight line passing through the origin, and from this fact I need to show that $u(x_p,t_p)=\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{x_p}{t_p}-\sqrt{gh_0}\right)$ and $c(x_p,t_p)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x_p}{t_p}+2\sqrt{gh_0}\right)$.

It makes sense for the $x_+$ characteristic to pass through the origin since there is no water at $x<0$ at the start, whereas if the characteristic started at $x>0$ then there would be crossing of $x_+$ characteristics. This forces $x_+(0)=0$. I don't know how to show that it is a straight line.

As for the part where I show $u(x_p,t_p)$ and $c(x_p,t_p)$ I have tried many different approaches for the past three hours and can't get anywhere.

Comment: The mathematical model of the physical problem seems not fully setteled. The two PDE are well defined. But the initial and/or boundary conditions might be not well posed. If the two sought functions are noted $u(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ can you write down on mathematical form (without physical description) $u(x,0)=?$ , $h(x,0)=?$ , $u(0,t)=?$ , $h(0,t)=?$ . If not, what is mathematically known and what is unknown among those conditions.

Comment: Since the water is at rest for $x>0$ at $t=0$, and since there is no water in the region $x\leq 0$ then I think $u(x,0)=0$. Similarly the depth is $h_0$ for $x>0$, and there is no water elsewhere, so for $x>0$, $h(x,0)=h_0$ and $h(x,0)=0$ elsewhere.

I am not sure about $u(0,t), h(0,t)$ - I don't think we can say anything about these really.

Comment: Sorry, the wording of the question confused me. Without knowing what exactly are the symbols used in the equations I misunderstood the question. Now I think that is a particular case of one-dimensional Saint-Venant equations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations . Your equations are a simplified case of the equations (1) and (2) of this paper, with $A$ proportional to $h$ and without the term on right of equation (2) that is no wall shear stress. References are provided concerning the method of characteristics applied in this case. Hoping that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dam-break problem is a particular Riemann problem for the shallow water equations in which the initial velocity $u(x,0)$ equals zero. Here, we consider the initial jump in water height $h$ with the values $h(x,0) = 0$ for negative abscissas and $h(x,0) = h_0>0$ for positive abscissas. A picture of the "minus" and "plus" base characteristics is shown below:

[image: characteristics]

With the notation $c=\sqrt{gh}$, the first family transports constant values of $R_- = u-2c$ at the speed $\lambda_- = u-c$, and the second family transports constant values of $R_+ = u+2c$ at the speed $\lambda_+ = u+c$. In the regions $x<0$ and $x>c_0 t$, the method of characteristics provides the values of
$$u = \tfrac12(R_+ + R_-), \qquad c = \tfrac14(R_+ - R_-) =\sqrt{gh}$$
which are deduced from the initial values of the Riemann invariants $R_\pm = 0$ and $R_\pm = \pm 2c_0$, respectively. It remains to determine what happens for $0< x < c_0 t$. From R.J. LeVeque (Cambridge University Press, 2002 -- Chap. 13)

> The shallow water equations are a system of two equations, and so the Riemann solution contains two waves. For the case of the dam-break problem [($u=0$ at $t=0$)], these always consist of one shock and one rarefaction wave

Obviously, we should consider a plus-rarefaction wave here (the plus-curves separate at $x=0$). If we place ourselves in the rarefaction fan at $(x_p, t_p)$ far away from the minus-shock (i.e., close to the line $x = c_0 t$), we can state that there is a plus-integral curve passing there. The later follows from the Ansatz $R_\pm = \tilde R_\pm(\xi)$ with $\xi = x/t$, and the relationship
$$
\left(\lambda_\pm - \xi\right) \tilde R'_\pm(\xi) = 0
$$
is deduced from the transport equations $\partial_t R_\pm + \lambda_\pm \partial_x R_\pm = 0$. For a plus-rarefaction wave along which $R_+$ varies, we therefore know that $\xi = \lambda_+$, and that $R_-$ is constant. Since $R_-$ is constant and equal to its value $-2c_0$ at some nearby point located on the line $x = c_0 t$, we can write the system
\begin{aligned}
u_p + \phantom{1} c_p &= x_p/t_p \\
u_p - 2 c_p &= -2c_0
\end{aligned}
which solution may be expressed as
$$
u_p = \frac23 \left(\frac{x_p}{t_p} - c_0\right) ,\qquad
c_p = \frac13 \left(\frac{x_p}{t_p} + 2c_0\right) .
$$